# create if statement in each text area line to see if it is null or not

Tags: java, if-statement, null, textarea, keylistener

In my code right now a string is added each time the user hits enter. What I want to do is have the text only be added to the line if the line is not empty. IF the line is empty I just want the line to remain blank. To show you what I am looking for I added a gif.

```
  public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
   if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER){

       text11.jt.setText(text11.jt.getText() + "     sam");


   }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Check the condition for text11.jt.getText() as blank.

Comment: Specifically `if(text11.jt.getText().equals(""))`

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the String from text11.jt.getText() is empty using String's isEmpty() method.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty()

How do you want to handle the user only pressing the space bar and nothing else? If you want to consider this "empty", then then you will need to remove all white space from the String before checking if it is empty:

```
String stringWithoutSpaces = inputString.replaceAll("\s+", "");
```

https://javaconceptoftheday.com/remove-white-spaces-from-string-in-java/